# How do I call a non-public method of a public class in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, public-method

I'm calling the twitter4j library using Clojure like so:

```
(def twitter (. (TwitterFactory.) getInstance))
```

This works fine when I call it as a script.  But when I use gen-class, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call public method of non-public class: public java.lang.Object twitter4j.TwitterFactoryBase.getInstance()
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you post a skeleton of your gen-class code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with it myself, but Meikel Brandmeyer did a nice writeup on gen-class once, maybe that will help you:

http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(def twitter (.getInstance (new TwitterFactory)))
```

Comment: That makes no difference whatsoever.  Why would it?

Comment: I don't know what's the cause for the difference (being a clojure newbie). However it works for me :)

Comment: Wait.  Really?  I thought the difference was just syntactic sugar (I actually prefer your way -- it seems "lispier" to me).

Comment: @sramsay - you're correct, there is no difference. In fact, you can see how the `Foo.` macro gets expanded to `new Foo` by entering `(macroexpand '(Foo.))` in your REPL. You can also expand `(.bar baz)` in the same way to `(. baz bar)`